# Android studio adb connection error?

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I am using android studio 1.4 version in ubuntu 12.4, but my any android device not detect in android studio. In android studio 1.3 it work nice but after update android studio 1.4 device detection problem occure

below error screenshot is given.

[image]

if anyone know about this problem please help me. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I got solution for this issue in android studio

Go to - **Run** Menu and select **Attach debugger to android process** stay connected you device while do this.

OR

Click on [image]  button on toolbar

Answer (score 0):

Your adb port is using from another program (could be android emulator Genymotion). You should open android studio, then open Genymotion.